# How are velocity vectors calculated when speed and change vector is given?

Tags: geometry, vectors, computational-geometry

This is related on an insanely hard geometry problem on Codeforces that I am struggling with:

[RC Kaboom Show](https://codeforces.com/contest/1359/problem/F)

**The jist of the problem is as follows:**

Given an infinite 2D field, you can place $n$ cars at any position so as they are not same as some other car's position.

You are also given a change vector $[d_x,d_y]$ which if you add it to the car's current position will result in the new changed position.

For example:

Initial position: $[3,0]$ + $[1,1]$ (Change vector) = $[4,1]$ (This is the new position of the car).

Pretty easy to understand so far.

**Now is where things go haywire:**

You are also given a speed $s$ for each car, along with its change vector. The car is suppose to move at this constant speed $s$. **What does speed even mean in this context ?**

**Should I multiply the change vector with the speed ?** In the solution the **speed is actually put to use by calculating a separate velocity vector** $[v_x,v_y]$. Technique for that is as follows:

1. Calculate $d_i$ as $\sqrt{(d_x)^2 + (d_y)^2}$. Please note that this would use the change vector for that particular car $i$.

One would think that is the distance between 2 points of a line, but I have no idea how that works here for by using the change vector. I mean the change vector does not represent the final position of the car, it just represents the change, thus I don't think $d$ is distance here.

2. $v_x = (d_x /d)s_i $
3. $v_x = (d_y /d)s_i $

So my question is simple - What on earth is going on here ? Is there method to this madness ?

**Does this technique of calculating velocity vectors have a name, so I can study it ?**

Do these problems fall under a type so maybe I can look at easier problems before this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you have the speed. Multiply it by time and you get distance. Since you position the cars in advance and interested just by the first collision, make sure the other cars doi not interfere...:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the actual definition from the link, with a couple of typos fixed and a change of variables for the direction:

> To be formal, for each car $i$ ($1 \le i \le n$) you choose its initial position $(x_i,y_i)$ and a direction vector $(X_i,Y_i)$. Moreover, each car has a constant speed $s_i$ units per second. So after car $i$ is launched, it starts moving from $(x_i, y_i)$ in the direction $(X_i, Y_i)$ with constant speed $s_i$.

This means that only the direction of $(X_i , Y_i)$ affects the movement per time step, not its magnitude.  The distance of each movement is specified solely by $s_i$.

In other words, the change in location per time step for car $i$ is $(\chi_i, \gamma_i)$,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\chi_i &= \displaystyle s_i \frac{X_i}{\sqrt{X_i^2 + Y_i^2}} \\
\gamma_i &= \displaystyle s_i \frac{X_i}{\sqrt{X_i^2 + Y_i^2}} \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
where the right side of $s_i$ is the direction vector $x$ and $y$ components scaled so that the length of the direction vector is $1$.

(In other words, if you have vector $(x, y)$, and you want to scale it to unit length, you get $(x / \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, y / \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$.  Your assumption that the car change vector would be $(X_i, Y_i)$ is incorrect; the rest of the confusion stems from that.  $(X_i, Y_i)$ only specifies the direction, not the "length" of each step.)

> Does this technique of calculating velocity vectors have a name, so I can study it ?

It is common to use a vector to indicate direction, with its length (as long as nonzero!) irrelevant.  In such cases, combined with speed as above, yields the *velocity vector*, which contains both direction and length.

So, this kind of construction, being given *direction vector* $(X_i, Y_i)$ and *speed* $s_i$, and constructing *velocity vector* $(\chi_i, \gamma_i)$ using the above, is actually rather common.

You encounter similar things in basic vector algebra and linear algebra, if you do for example 3D rotations and transforms.  You use cross product between some two vectors (typically directions at different times) to find an axis vector; and many rotation methods require you to first *normalize that axis vector to unit length* in exactly the same way (well, without a "speed").

You could ask why not specify the direction using an unit vector in the first place, or why not specify the direction as an angle $\varphi$ counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis (in which case $X_i = \cos\varphi$, and $Y_i = \sin\varphi$, and they form an unit vector, $X_i^2 + Y_i^2 = 1$).  The answer to that is an unsatisfying "we must work with the input we get, not with the input we'd prefer".  That, too, is very common.

---

In the problem, the input contains $x_i$, $y_i$, $X_i$, $Y_i$, and $s_i$ for $n$ cars ($i = 1, 2, \dots, n-1, n$ or $i = 0, 1, \dots, n-2, n-1$, whichever you prefer), and the user is to find their launching times $t_i \ge 0$ so that the first collision occurs as soon (at as small time $t$ as possible).

It is very important to realize that using the velocity vectors $(\chi_i, \gamma_i)$ calculated as above, at time $t$ the position of car $i$ is
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_i^\prime &= \begin{cases} x_i, & t \le t_i \\
x_i + (t - t_i) \chi_i, & t \ge t_i \end{cases} \\
y_i^\prime &= \begin{cases} y_i, & t \le t_i \\
y_i + (t - t_i) \gamma_i, & t \ge t_i \end{cases} \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
*noting that none of these have to be integers*, they can be reals (floating-point values) instead.  (I couldn't think of any new $x$- and $y$-looking letters to use for the position coordinate variables, so I used the prime mark, $\,^\prime$, to indicate these are new variables; these read as *"x-prime i"* and *"y-prime i"*, respectively.)

So, there are no *steps* in time here, really; a time "step" is just one unit of time.

Furthermore, the problem states a collision between car $i$ and car $k$ occurs at time $t$ if the coordinates differ by at most $10^{-6} = 0.000001$, i.e.
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\left\lvert x_i^\prime - x_k^\prime \right\rvert & \le 10^{-6} \\
\left\lvert y_i^\prime - y_k^\prime \right\rvert & \le 10^{-6} \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
but you are better off using a slightly tighter limit, distance between the coordinates less than $10^{-6}$, or better yet, squared distance between the coordinates less than $(10^{-6})^2 = 10^{-12}$.

Therefore, the actual problem is to find $i$, $k$, $t_i$, and $t_k$, such that at the smallest $t$, $t \ge 0$,
$$(x_i^\prime - x_k^\prime)^2 + (y_i^\prime - y_k^\prime)^2 \le 10^{-12}$$

Hint:

One of the cars must start at time $t = 0$, the other can start at the same time or later.  If we pick $t_i = 0$, and solve for cars $i$ and $k$ having the same coordinates ($x_i^\prime = x_k^\prime$, $y_i^\prime = x_k^\prime$) at time $t$ for $t$ and $t_k$, we get
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\Delta &= \chi_k \gamma_i - \chi_i \gamma_k \\
t &= \displaystyle \frac{ \gamma_k ( x_i - x_k ) - \chi_k ( y_i - y_k ) }{\Delta} \\
t_k &= \displaystyle \frac{ (\gamma_k - \gamma_i)(x_i - x_k) - (\chi_k - \chi_i)(y_i - y_k) }{\Delta} \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
where $\Delta = 0$ if the two cars cannot intersect, and $t \ge t_k$ for the coordinates of car $k$ to be valid.

Collision between stationary car $k$ and car $i$ started at $t_i = 0$ occurs at
$t = (x_k - x_i) / \chi_i$ if $t \ge 0$ and $\lvert y_i + t \gamma_i - y_k \rvert \le 10^{-6}$;
or at $t = (y_k - y_i) / \gamma_i$ if $t \ge 0$ and $\lvert x_i + t \chi_i - x_k \rvert \le 10^{-6}$, whichever gives the smaller nonnegative $t$, using the rules of this problem.

---

I recommend you install yourself the free and open source computer algebra system [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/download.html).  I found the above solutions using the text-only interface, via

```
display2d:false;

solve([ x_i + t*chi_i = x_k + (t - t_k)*chi_k,
        y_i + t*gamma_i = y_k + (t - t_k)*gamma_k ], [ t, t_k ]);

solve( x_i + t*chi_i = x_k, t);
```

and it gives

```
[[t = -(chi_k*(y_i-y_k)+gamma_k*x_k-gamma_k*x_i)
    /(chi_k*gamma_i-chi_i*gamma_k),
  t_k = -(chi_i*(y_k-y_i)+chi_k*(y_i-y_k)+(gamma_k-gamma_i)*x_k
                         +(gamma_i-gamma_k)*x_i)
      /(chi_k*gamma_i-chi_i*gamma_k)]]

[t = (x_k-x_i)/chi_i]
```

It has a nice GUI too, but I do not often use that, as I have a very old and slow computer, and prefer the text interface.  There are others like Maxima too, like Sagemath.

Having such math tools is very important for every programmer, because while fine-tuning the code can give you a few percent increase in efficiency, using a better algorithm can make the program an order of magnitude (10×) more efficient (in run time and/or memory use).

Good luck with solving the problem!

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I am still in the process of understanding the full thing. But let me ask you some basic doubts that are still not crystal clear to me. 1) When a change vector $[X_i, Y_i]$ what do the numbers $X_i$ and $Y_i$ mean ? I mean if the magnitude is not important then what is the meaning of  the $x$ and $y$ components ? This misunderstanding stems from the very basic fact that I don't really understand what a vector is - what is meant by only direction and no magnitude here. **Let me know if this warrants a separate question**.

Comment: @ng.newbie: The numbers themselves aren't important, their *ratio* is.  If the direction is more along the $x$ axis than $y$ axis, then $Y_i/X_i$ is the slope of the direction. Or, if we measure angles from positive $x$ axis counterclockwise, then the direction is `atan2(Y[i], X[i])` (in radians, i.e. $2\pi$ is a full rotation).

Comment: @ng.newbie: A vector has direction and magnitude (or length). In two dimensions, we can specify the exact same vector using either Cartesian coordinates $x$ and $y$, or angle $\varphi$ and magnitude/length $r$ using $$\vec{p} = \left[ \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} r \cos\varphi \\ r \sin\varphi \end{matrix} \right]$$ where $$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \quad \varphi = \operatorname{atan2}\left(y, x\right)$$where $\operatorname{atan2}$ is the two-argument form of arcus tangent.  Look into **basic vector algebra**; it is very useful for programming work.

Comment: I am looking into vector algebra. But I have one confusing doubt. Vectors typically involve starting from the origin example, $[5,3]$ involves the vector being drawn from $[0,0]$. If we have to draw a vector from an arbitrary starting point then  we translate the point to the origin and then plot the vector. Here the initial position of the car can be thought of as such a point, **then when calculating the velocity vector why are we not doing any translation ?** I mean the velocity starts from the car's initial point and not the origin.

Comment: Basically asking if the starting point of the car is not the origin then wouldn't future vector calculations involve translating that point to the origin and then deriving the velocity vector ? I am really confused.

Comment: @ng.newbie: Translation only makes sense for vectors that specify a point.  Relative vectors, like velocity, or a vector between two points ($\overline{A B} = B - A$), are only rotated, because they are already relative to something.  Consider, for example, a car at origin, with velocity vector $(1,0)$.  After one unit of time, the car is now at $(1,0)$.  Should the velocity vector now change, too?  No, because the way we've defined velocity vectors make them relative.  Now, if we used instead position vectors that say "after one time unit, the car will be *there*", we'd need to [...]

Comment: @ng.newbie: [...] translate those as well, because they're positions, and only positions get translated.  (In simplest terms, that is.)  But that would make the math more complex for no good reason.

Comment: Ok, thanks once again for answering my doubts. **I am having trouble with the wording from the editorial** : > For some fixed $t$ car $i$ can end up in any point from $(x_i,y_i)$ to $s_i⋅t$ units along the ray $((x_i,y_i),(x_i+dx_i,y_i+dy_i))$. That makes it a segment.

**What I understand from the above statement: ** Distance = speed * time, so at any given time Distance traveled is $s_i * t$ for car $i$. The point at which the car will be at time $t$ will be along the ray $((x_i,y_i),(x_i+dx_i,y_i+dy_i))$. Since a ray has no end point it may surpass the point $(x_i+dx_i,y_i+dy_i)$..

Comment: [..] But at any point in time, I know car $i$ must be at some point $x_t, y_t$. So a line segment can be drawn from $x_i,y_i$ to $x_t,y_t$. **This is what make it a line segment and not a ray.** Am I correct ?

Comment: @ng.newbie: I think that is correct.  A line is infinite; a ray has a starting point but extends to infinity; and a line segment has a starting and an ending point.  The wording uses "along the ray" to emphasize that only the starting point and direction is fixed, and the other endpoint of the line segment depends on what you choose for $s_i$ (and $t$).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but do you know how the rest of the problem is solved ? I can't make head or tails by reading the editorial.